# Umbraco 10 Examine search, to return matches found in page titles and content

Tags: c#, umbraco, examine

I'm trying to build a search to return both matching page titles and matching content from within content pages.

I have included the code from [here](https://dev.to/jemayn/indexing-blocklist-data-in-umbraco-9-334o) to index blocklist content as well. I can find matching page titles no problem but no matter what I try I can't get it to find anything within page content.

Can anyone post a link to an example that works?

At the moment I'm working with this:

```
public IEnumerable<ResultItem?> SearchUmbraco(string searchTerm, int websiteId)
        {
              var examineSearcher = _examineManager.TryGetIndex("ExternalIndex", out var externalIndex)
                  ? externalIndex.Searcher
                  : null;

              var criteria = examineSearcher?.CreateQuery("content").GroupedOr(new[] { "nodeName", "content" }, searchTerm);

            var filter = criteria.Field("nodeName",     
            ISearchResults results = filter.Execute();

            // convert the results to a list of ResultItem objects while filtering out irrelevant results from other sites etc
            var content = results.Select(x => ConvertToResult(int.Parse(x.Id), websiteId, x.Score))
                  .Where(x => x != null)
            .ToList();

              return content.OrderByDescending(x => x.score);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full-working code from one of my Umbraco v10 websites, for a similar search:

```
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{
    private readonly IExamineManager _examineManager;
    private readonly UmbracoHelper _umbracoHelper;

    public SearchService(IExamineManager examineManager, UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper)
    {
        _examineManager = examineManager;
        _umbracoHelper = umbracoHelper;
    }
    public ReadOnlyPagedCollection<SiteSearchModel> GetSearchItems(int page, string query, string filterValue, string searchPath, string noResultsMessage, int itemsPerPage)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> ids = Array.Empty<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) && _examineManager.TryGetIndex("ExternalIndex", out IIndex index))
        {
            var textFields = new[] { "nodeName", "pageTitle", "title", "titleSecondRow", "description", "modules", "homeModules", "topInformationBox", "signpost", "summary", "threeCardDesign", "seoDescription", "mainContent", "articleDate" };
            ids = index
            .Searcher
            .CreateQuery(IndexTypes.Content).GroupedOr(textFields, query)
            .Execute()
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
            .Select(x => x.Id);
        }

        IList<SiteSearchModel> siteSearchAll = new List<SiteSearchModel>();
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var publishedPage = _umbracoHelper.Content(id);
            if (publishedPage != null && publishedPage.HasProperty("hideFromSiteSearch") && !publishedPage.GetProperty("hideFromSiteSearch").GetValue().ToString().Equals(Boolean.TrueString))
            {
                siteSearchAll.Add(publishedPage.ToSiteSearch());
            }
        }

        IList<SiteSearchModel> siteSearchNews = siteSearchAll.Where(s => s.Path.Contains(AppConstants.Search.NewsPath)).ToList();
        IList<SiteSearchModel> siteSearchCorporate = siteSearchAll.Where(s => s.Path.Contains(AppConstants.Search.CorporatePath)).ToList();
        IList<SiteSearchModel> siteSearchAirportInformation = siteSearchAll.Where(s => s.Path.Contains(AppConstants.Search.AirportInformationPath)).ToList();

        Dictionary<SearchFilter, int> resultCountByFilter = new Dictionary<SearchFilter, int>();

        resultCountByFilter.Add(SearchFilter.All, siteSearchAll.Count());
        resultCountByFilter.Add(SearchFilter.News, siteSearchNews.Count());
        resultCountByFilter.Add(SearchFilter.Corporate, siteSearchCorporate.Count());
        resultCountByFilter.Add(SearchFilter.AirportInformation, siteSearchAirportInformation.Count());

        IList<SiteSearchModel> siteSearchByFilter = new List<SiteSearchModel>();
        switch (filterValue)
        {
            case AppConstants.Search.AirportInformation:
                siteSearchByFilter = siteSearchAirportInformation;
                break;
            case AppConstants.Search.News:
                siteSearchByFilter = siteSearchNews;
                break;
            case AppConstants.Search.Corporate:
                siteSearchByFilter = siteSearchCorporate;
                break;
            default:
                siteSearchByFilter = siteSearchAll;
                break;
        }

        var totalPages = siteSearchByFilter != null && siteSearchByFilter.Any() ? (int)Math.Ceiling((double)siteSearchByFilter.Count() / itemsPerPage) : 0;
        if (page > totalPages || page <= 0)
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        var newsListing = new ListingModel(page, totalPages);
        return new ReadOnlyPagedCollection<SiteSearchModel>(siteSearchByFilter.Skip((page - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList(), newsListing, resultCountByFilter, query, filterValue, noResultsMessage);
    }
}
```

Here is the ISearchService:

```
public interface ISearchService
{
    public ReadOnlyPagedCollection<SiteSearchModel> GetSearchItems(int page, string query, string filterValue, string searchPath, string noResultsMessage, int itemsPerPage);
}
```

ReadOnlyPagedCollection:

```
public class ReadOnlyPagedCollection<T>
{
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; set; }
    public ListingModel Pagination { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<SearchFilter, int> ResultsCount { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
    public string NoResultsMessage { get; set; }
    public ReadOnlyPagedCollection(IReadOnlyList<T> items, ListingModel pagination)
    {
        Items = items;
        Pagination = pagination;
    }
    public ReadOnlyPagedCollection(IReadOnlyList<T> items, ListingModel pagination, Dictionary<SearchFilter, int> resultsCount, string query, string filterValue, string noResultsMessage)
    {
        Items = items;
        Pagination = pagination;
        ResultsCount = resultsCount;
        Query = query;
        FilterValue = filterValue;
        NoResultsMessage = noResultsMessage;
    }
}
```

SiteSearchModel:

```
public class SiteSearchModel
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageSummary { get; set; }
    public SiteSearchModel(IPublishedContent page)
    {
        Path = page.Url(mode: UrlMode.Absolute);
        PageTitle = page.HasProperty("pageTitle") ? page.GetProperty("pageTitle").GetValue().ToString() : string.Empty;
        PageSummary = page.HasProperty("summary") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(page.GetProperty("summary")?.GetValue().ToString()) ? page.GetProperty("summary").GetValue().ToString() : page.HasProperty("seoDescription") ? page.GetProperty("seoDescription").GetValue().ToString() : string.Empty;
    }
}
```